# The first of three

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I found this word to be quite poetic and saw @PerpetualJ's comment (saying to make another riddle), so here it is:

> It is the plot of many works
>   All in one word
>   The first step is to break it into three
>   And take the first and swap with the second
>   and what results is the first of three
>   Next, you must undo your last
>   and what you find is the second
>   Your last mission is to put it all back
>   and double the first two
>   and there you will connect the final three
>   and you will see
>   the answer

Disclaimer (Sort of a hint as well...):

> In the process of solving, the word will be turned into phrases. The final answer should include the word, all the phrases, and the final phrase. (partial answers are still allowed)

Hint 1:

> The first and third line is key to the word itself, then work on the rest.

Hint 2:

> The word is not compound, yet it has words inside. Ex: Office => Off Ice

Hint 3:

> The word is 8 letters long, so think small words that are in the word.

Hint 4:

> You break the word into three parts and then you can do the actions it states, so you could find the three words first.

Hint 5:

> The first word in the word is 2 letters, the second is 3, and the last one is also 3.

Comment: If only it would notify me when someone puts my name in a post like this? How about it all mighty SE developers?

Comment: I'll need to `ponder` this one for a minute. :)

Comment: This is the least active of all of my questions. Maybe posted at the wrong time.

Comment: A hint will now be given every 50 views.

Comment: is the suffix r13(vba)?

Comment: No, but good guess!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **TOGETHER**

*It is the plot of many works*
*All in one word*

> A common plot in movies, TV and books follows the efforts of a man (or woman) to win the affections of the girl of their dreams, i.e. **TO/GET/HER**.

---

**Part 1 - 'the first of three'**
*The first step is to break it into three*
*And take the first and swap with the second*
*and what results is the first of three*

> Break the word into three parts as above, and exchange the first two to get **GET/TO/HER**.

**Part 2 - 'the second' [of three]**
*Next, you must undo your last*
*and what you find is the second*

> Put the words back in order and you have (as outlined at the top): **TO/GET/HER**.

**Part 3**
*Your last mission is to put it all back*
*and double the first two*

> Put it all back to get **TOGETHER** and 'double the first two' [syllables] to get (!) an extra **TO/GET**.

**'Connect the final three'**
*and there you will connect the final three*
*and you will see*
*the answer*

> Finally, put all three parts together to get one long tongue-twister of a phrase:
>  **GET TO HER TO GET HER, TO GET TOGETHER!**

Comment: 100% correct! Congratulations! :) +1

Comment: Thanks @Duck - the hint giving the lengths of the words was a real help!

Comment: Took a while to make, was considering this word in one since my last question. Glad you liked it!

Answer (score 1):

Very partial, and most likely wrong, but could the first word be:

> betrayal

That's the right number of letters (via hint), and a common plot in many books and movies..  And, it can be broken into three words (had to check that the last one is an allowed Scrabble word):

> bet-ray-al     or      be-tray-al

As much as I want it to work, I can't make any of the follow-up instructions make any sense...

Comment: Well first, the word itself does not correspond to that line, the words in the word does. Sorry, but not correct. +1 :)