# Ask [prefix] [infix] [suffix] permission. What's [whole]?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> Ask [prefix] [infix] [suffix] permission.

With the above a grammatical and logical statement, what is [whole]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> TOGETHER

Reasoning

> "Ask **TO GET HER** permission"
>  is a grammatical and logical statement and the words join to form the word **TOGETHER**

Also

> There is an inherent hint in that we are joining the prefix, infix, suffix **TOGETHER**.

Comment: Related [puzzle from the past](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87481/the-first-of-three)...

Answer (score 15):

There's a somewhat uncommon English word which satisfies this statement:

> **[THEREFOR](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefor)**, a word meaning '*for, or in exchange for this/that*' in the sense of "You've returned this item so I'll give you a refund therefor." (NB This is a different meaning to the more commonly used but similar-appearing 'therefore'...)
>
>  The statement then becomes: *Ask **THE_** ***REF*** **_FOR** permission.* This would be perfectly valid in the context of a sports match where a player is advised to speak to the referee (commonly, 'ref') with a request...

Comment: Actually, this is also a good answer.

Comment: Isn't there an extra F in there? THEREFFOR

Comment: @RoundTower The way the affix-riddles usually work, you're allowed overlap between the different -fixes :) So that 'F' only appears once in the whole word but can be used in more than one of its divisions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to build a place to relax... I'll need to ask

> **for rest station**

permission.

What could be more relaxing than

> building it in the middle of some natural **forestation**

If there's not enough in my area, perhaps I need to ask

> **for rest land**

permission. I can then

> plant some trees to make some more **forestland**.